# flush output in Bourne Shell

Tags: linux, shell, upstart

I use echo in Upstart scripts to log things:

```
script
    echo "main: some data" >> log
end script

post-start script
    echo "post-start: another data" >> log
end script
```

Now these two run in parallel, so in the logs I often see:

```
main: post-start: some data another data
```

This is not critical, so I won't employ proper synching, but thought I'd turn auto flush ON to at least reduce this effect. Is there an easy way to do that?

Update: yes, flushing will not properly fix it, but I've seen it help such situations to some degree, and this is all I need in this case. It's just that I don't know how to do it in Shell

Comment: I don't see how auto-flush could help you with that.

Comment: Auto flush is not going to help you. Are  the logs actually conveying "some data" twice, or is the second one actually "same data"?

Comment: 2 tinkertim: no, this is different "some data". I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
echo "text"
```

To:

```
cat << EOF
text
EOF
```

Comment: I suspected they might write differently (different buffer sizes, etc.), and it worked for me. Of course you can't entirely fix the problem without locking of some sort, but choice of write method might make it less noticeable.

Comment: I guess that's true. The echo is a built-in command, so it caches, when cat is an executable, so it'll flush when exiting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I usually use trailing `|grep -F --line-buffered ''` as a cheap and reliable way to enforce line buffering. There's also `sponge` from *moreutils* to delay all output until input is finished and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume that flushing would help? The write done by echo includes a newline, so if the first script ran to completion before the second, the newline would already by there.

In the output it isn't, which indicates that the second script was run before the first was complete, thus interleaving their outputs.

Flushing won't help with this, it's a "proper" parallel race condition.

Comment: flushing won't fix this completely but will make the writing slightly mode atomic, which will reduce the probability of this happening.

I didn't really give the exact output or the exact commands, so please don't rely on them too much. The real output is different.